# Numerically finding $\delta$ given an $\epsilon$ for a continuous map from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^m$.

Tags: real-analysis, numerical-methods, continuity

Given an explicit continuous map $f:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ and an $\epsilon$ is it possible to numerically compute a required $\delta$ that could be used to show that the definition of continuity holds for this $\epsilon$? Where each space has the Euclidean norm.

Are there any conditions on $f$ or the image of $f$ etc. which would allow $\delta$ to be computed?

The examples I'm specifically interested in are charts of Manifolds if that helps.

Comment: Is this uniform continuity or pointwise continuity? Do you have some easy way to compute $\sup_{y,0<|x-y|<\delta} |f(x)-f(y)|$ as a function of $x$ and $\delta$?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure. The more general the case, the better. I don't have a particular function in mind, I'm just curious for general cases. So it could computing $sup...$ is not necessarily easy.

Comment: If you know literally nothing other than continuity then this will honestly be pretty difficult. Even if you know differentiability but no *quantitative* idea about the derivative, you're in for some trouble.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your response. Do you know of any conditions on $f$ or any additional information that would allow $\delta$ to be computed? The more general the better.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about continuous  mappings, but if $f$ is differentiable in $x_0$ then you have 
$$ f(x) = f(x_0) + f'(x_0)(x-x_0) + o(\|x-x_0\|)$$
from which follows that
$$ \|f(x)-f(x_0)\| \le \|f'(x_0)\|\cdot\|x-x_0\|  + \|o(\|x-x_0\|)\|$$
Given that your norm $\|\cdot\|$ is sub-multiplicative. So for given $\epsilon>0$ one can choose $\delta = \frac{\epsilon}{2\|f'(x_0)\|}$ since then:
$$
\|f(x)-f(x_0)\| \le \frac{1}{2}\epsilon + \|o(\epsilon)\|<\epsilon \qquad\text{for small enough }\epsilon
$$